# MySQL: Migrate MyISAM table with multicolumn primary index with autoincrement to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, primary-key, myisam, auto-increment

I have a large (10M rows) MyISAM table with a primary index on 2 different columns where one of them is auto_increment.
How can I migrate it to InnoDB in MySQL 5.7?
The table is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `dailyCounterId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tickets`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dailyCounterId`,`counter`);

ALTER TABLE `tickets`
  MODIFY `counter` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

I already tried to change the engine but I receive a 1075 error code.
It seems that in innoDB I cannot have a primary key on 2 columns and auto_increment on one of them.

I also tried to create an ID column with primary key and auto_increment, and create another unique index on my two columns but when I try to edit the counter column for add auto_increment, I receive again an error where only 1 auto_increment can exist.

The main goal is to be able to have a unique counter for every dailyCounterId, and I cannot do it with a `MAX(counter)+1` logic because I have lots of concurrency on this table.

Thanks

Comment: that is not how auto_increment works. so don't do that at all, and a row number, should be added in a select

Comment: Secondary autoincremented column is not supported in InnoDB, this is MyISAM only feature. You may emulate it using trigger and additional table. For example, you may split the table, staying PK columns on MyISAM and complete structure on InnoDB.

Comment: I discuss this issue, and a possible work-around, in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb